# Redirect an active user with status 1 and 3 in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

in my Laravel 5.2 project, I have **user** table which has a status field having 3 values. The values are , **0=not active, 1=active, 2 = paid**. After login I want to check whether the user is having statuses 1 or 3. ***If they belongs to status 1 or 3 then I need to redirect to dashboard. Else nothing***. The below is my getcredential method in AuthController.

```
protected function getCredentials($request) {

 return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password') + ['status' => 1];
}
```

How can I check both statuses here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. I kept the getCredential method as it is.

```
protected function getCredentials($request) {
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password') +
    ['status' => 1];
}
```

And I wrote the following code in login function in AuthController.

```
if($user->status == 3){
 if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'], 'status' => 3,])) 
                     {

                        $fallback_url =  '/dashboard';
                        $intended_url = 
                                Redirect::intended($fallback_url)->getTargetUrl();
                        return response()->json(['auth' => true, 'intended' => $intended_url]);

                    }
  }
```

And now users with status = 1 and status =3 can login to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The value for a credential does not need to be a static value, you can also provide a `Closure` that will be executed by the user provider on the query it uses to check credentials.

The following should do the trick:

```
protected function getCredentials($request) {
  return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password') + ['status' => function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('status', [1, 3]);
  }];
}
```

Comment: But if I use this, it will be like select * from users where email = 'ddd' and status = (select * from status ....) . Here status and email both belongs to user table itself.

Comment: Why would it search the status table? It will still use the table your user provider is using to fetch user data. It will just do ‘where status in (1,3)’ instead of checking for a single value.